# How do I sort my array of data on an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using angular, I'm pulling data from my API. I'm unsure about two things if someone could give me insight:

1. Should I be sorting the array on the `Observable` or the `Subscriber` and why?
2. I'm unsure how to sort my array of data based off if the values are true or false using the `sort()` function.

Here is what my object looks like, if any of the values after hostname come back false, or if the date on `UpdatedDate` is over 4 weeks, I need that object to show first. If everything is true, but the date is > 2 weeks and also < 4 weeks, I need it to come second. And if the object is completely true with a date that is less than 2 weeks old, I want it to come last.  There will be about 500 of these `Ipcidata` objects coming through.

```
export interface Ipcidata {
    id: Int16Array;
    hostname: string;
    AMStatus: boolean;
    BLStatus: boolean;
    FirewallRullStatus: boolean;
    FirewallContentStatus: boolean;
    SCCMStatus: boolean;
    MSBaselineStatus: boolean;
    UpdatedDate: Date;
    USBStatus: boolean;
}
```

Here's my observable, with a sort function ready

```
  getPciInfo(): Observable <Ipcidata[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Ipcidata[]>('http://localhost:499/api/PCImachines').pipe(
      map(results => results.sort()
      )
    );
  }
```

Lastly, here's some logic I wrote that does exactly what I need to check for:

```
  sortObjects(){
    const latest_date = this.datepipe.transform(this.systemInput.UpdatedDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
    if (latest_date > this.dateMinusTwoWeeks
    && this.systemInput.AMStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.BLStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.FirewallRullStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.FirewallContentStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.SCCMStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.MSBaselineStatus == true
    && this.systemInput.USBStatus == true
    ){return true }
    else if(latest_date > this.dateMinusMonth && latest_date < this.dateMinusTwoWeeks
      && this.systemInput.AMStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.BLStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.FirewallRullStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.FirewallContentStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.SCCMStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.MSBaselineStatus == true
      && this.systemInput.USBStatus == true
      ){return 'datewarning'; }
        else {return false}
    }
```

I've tried to work this into the sort function using online resources, but I'm relatively new to all of this. Some help and a brief explanation would be much appreciated.

#### UPDATE:

My sort object is now sorting, but it's also updating the properties on my object. For example, it is randomly changing the values of `b.USBstatus` to `false`. I just want it to display this object first if all these flags are true. what am I doing wrong?

```
results.sort(function(a,b) { 
        if (b.AMStatus == true
          && b.BLStatus == true
          && b.FirewallRullStatus == true
          && b.FirewallContentStatus == true
          && b.SCCMStatus == true
          && b.MSBaselineStatus == true
          && b.USBStatus == true
          ){
        return -1;
        }
    })));
  }
```

Comment: As an aside, you can remove all `== true`. Anything truthy will satisfy the condition.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks. As I was fixing this up I did that shortly after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.sort()` takes `compareFunction` as parameter.

i.e. `result.sort(sortObjects)`

The logic behind `compareFunction` is that it should take two parameters, `firstElement` and `secondElement`, say `a` and `b`.

Then the compareFunction should look something like this,

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

[SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) - JavaScript Docs

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do I need a "b" parameter if I'm just checking for true or false values? Can I omit that and just use "if a.property = false return 1"?  

Return also seems to be changing the actual values rather than just deciding which ICIData object to display first. Not sure why that is happening.   Basically, I don't want to change any of the properties on each object, but just decide which object comes first when displaying the data based off the properties.

Comment: Do you wanna sort or filter? If you wanna sort then you need to compare two things then dicide where to put which one.

Comment: I'd like to decide which of the IPCIData objects displays in the array first, not really re-arrange any properties inside the objects.  The properties inside the objects just decide if they are one of the ones that comes first.  So I'm pretty sure I still want to use Sort right?

Comment: The above doesn't rearrange properties and you can't. This just sorts array of IPCIData objects with some condition.

Comment: Interesting, when I return 1 after the if statement,  it actually updates the value of that property from 0 to 1. I don't want to change the actual properties.  I'm assuming (and from what I read) that the -1, 1, and 0 are meant to order the objects. Why is it changing the values?

Comment: Because **you need to write different compare function, not use what you have or sortObjects function wont work**

Comment: I've wrote a completely different function, and posted the code above. It for whatever reason is still changing the property / object values before it is mapped, rather than just changing the order of the objects.

Comment: @st0rch1991 Use `tap` instead of `map`

Comment: Still doing the same thing with tap.  As I understand it, these are sorting the values inside the objects, and not the objects themselves right? Is there any way to sort the lower level objects and the order which they appear in the array of objects without manipulating the values?

Comment: This ended up working. Thank you for your patience and explanation. I read through the documentation as well and now have a much better understanding of sorting my data in general. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Should I be sorting the array on the Observable or the Subscriber and why?**

In general I would sort as soon as possible. When your data set is used on other locations of your application where it is not sorted, then sorting within subscription is fine. Otherwise I think sorting with pipe is better. This also fits to the general approach to avoid subscriptions and use async pipe instead.

**2 - I'm unsure how to sort my array of data based off if the values are true or false using the sort() function.**

See Vishnudev's answer